# Rails ActiveSupport Issue with state gems for notifications

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, activerecord, rubygems

I have installed multiple state_machine gems to my app to use them for a notification system but every time I run into an ActiveSupport issue.  It usually looks something almost identical to this:

```
>> m = Message.new
TypeError: wrong argument type nil (expected Module)
        from /home/Ryan/appname/app/models/message.rb:2:in `include'
        from /home/Ryan/appname/app/models/message.rb:2
        from /home/Ryan/.bundle/ruby/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.9/lib/active_sup
port/dependencies.rb:406:in `load_without_new_constant_marking'
        from /home/Ryan/.bundle/ruby/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.9/lib/active_sup
port/dependencies.rb:406:in `load_file'
        from /home/Ryan/.bundle/ruby/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.9/lib/active_sup
port/dependencies.rb:547:in `new_constants_in'
        from /home/Ryan/.bundle/ruby/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.9/lib/active_sup
port/dependencies.rb:405:in `load_file'
        from /home/Ryan/.bundle/ruby/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.9/lib/active_sup
port/dependencies.rb:285:in `require_or_load'
        from /home/Ryan/.bundle/ruby/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.9/lib/active_sup
port/dependencies.rb:451:in `load_missing_constant'
        from /home/Ryan/.bundle/ruby/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.9/lib/active_sup
port/dependencies.rb:106:in `rake_original_const_missing'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2503:in `const_m
issing'
        from /home/Ryan/.bundle/ruby/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.9/lib/active_sup
port/dependencies.rb:118:in `const_missing'
        from (irb):2
```

I'm on a windows 7 machine using activerecord, bundler to install the gems, and rails 2.3.9..where am I going wrong? Is there some modification to the database I need to be making?

```
Edit: message.rb

    include AlterEgo # include this first
    include AlterEgo::ActiveRecordAdapter

    state :unread, :default => true do
      handle :state do
    "unread"
      end
      transition :to => :read, :on => :view!
    end

    state :read do
      handle :state do
    "read"
      end
    end
```

I'm not positive, but I am having trouble adapting this for activerecord.  do i need to create a new database?

Comment: We need more information line you Answer class, where the error is raised

Comment: edited the question to include message.rb (sorry, forgot to change that from answer to message!)...it been several variations of this code for all the state machines i've tried (pretty much all of them)...as you can see, the use I have for it is very simple.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT

I ended up just using oldschool acts_as_state_machine since this is such a simple implementation